# Spanish idiom for being very frightened

Tags: modismos

What would be a Spanish (Spain) equivalent to these common English expressions for being very afraid:

It scared me (half) to death!

It scared the hell out of me!

It scared the crap out of me!

Comment: Casi me mató de susto.

Comment: A vulgar idiom we sometimes use is "Me cagué en las patas".

Comment: Me cagué patas abajo, also vulgar but used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expresiones y localismos

- ¡Qué susto! / con tono de terror
- Casi me matas del susto / (It scared me (half) to death!)
- Caerse del susto / (It scared the hell out of me!)
- Dar un susto de muerte / Pegar un susto de muerto (Me has dado un susto de muerte, me han pegado el susto de la muerte) / (It scared the crap out of me!)
- Me he cagado del susto.
- Que susto me has dado, tienes el demonio en el cuerpo.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most commonly used expressions in Spain are:
Morirse de miedo, estar muerto de miedo
Me dio un susto de muerte.
[vulg] Me dio un susto de la hostia
[vulg] Cagarse de miedo

Answer (score 0):

Otras posibles opciones, que indican la imposibilidad de ninguna acción, a causa del miedo estremecedor que se está sufriendo:

- **clavado** (por el miedo).
- **inmovilizado** (por el miedo).
- **paralizado** (por el miedo).

Answer (score 0):

It scared me (half) to death = Me asusto de muerte.
It scared the hell out of me! =¡Me asustó muchísimo!.
It scared the crap out of me! = Me    ha dado un susto de muerte.

Basically they all translate the same into Spanish and express a feeling of surprise, fright and fear in a colloquial way.A more informal way of expressing the same would be:

- Me cague del miedo
- Me mataste del susto